# Linq to select data from one table not in other table

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, linq

Hi i have the following code to select data from one table not in other table

```
var result1 = (from e in db.Users
               select e).ToList();
var result2 = (from e in db.Fi
               select e).ToList();
List<string> listString = (from e in result1
                           where !(from m in result2
                                   select m.UserID).Contains(e.UserID)
                           select e.UserName).ToList();

ViewBag.ddlUserId = listString;
```

Am getting value inside listString .But got error while adding listString to viewbag.

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String]' to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Main.Models.Admin.User]'.
```

Comment: Check the Data type of `ddlUserId` , may be mismatch with string !

Comment: Looks like ViewBag.ddlUserId is expecting a IEnumerable of User objects. but the result of the query is a list of strings

Comment: I think Admin User is an enum.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

First, could you update your question with the entire method so that we can see what might be going on with the `ViewBag`? Because your code should work just fine, assigning whatever value to the ViewBag is no problem normally:

```
    ViewBag.property1 = 0;
    ViewBag.property1 = "zero";
```

works just fine. `ViewBag` is dynamic. Now, you could get that error if you would later try to assing `ViewBag.ddlUserId` to something that actually is the wrong type.

I would like you to rewrite your statement as well, let me explain why. Assume for a moment that you have a lot ( > 100.000) of `User` records in your `db.Users`  and we assume the same for `Fi` as well. In your code, `result1` and `result2` are now two lists, one containing >100.000 `User` objects and the other >100.000 `Fi` objects. Then these two lists are compared to each other to produce a list of strings. Now imagine the resource required for your web server to process this. Under the assumption that your actually using/accessing a separate SQL server to retrieve your data from, it would be a lot better and faster to let that server do the work, i.e. producing the list of UserID's.
For that you'd either use Kirill Bestemyanov's answer or the following:

```
    var list = (from user in db.Users
                where !db.Fi.Any(f => f.UserID == user.UserID)
                select user.UserName).ToList()
```

This will produce just one query for the SQL server to execute:

```
    SELECT 
    [Extent1].[UserName] AS [UserName]
    FROM [dbo].[Users] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 
        1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[Fi] AS [Extent2]
    WHERE [Extent2].[UserID] = [Extent1].[UserID]
    )}
```

which in the end is what you want...

Just to clarify more:

```
    var list = (from user in db.Users
                where !db.Fi.Any(f => f.UserID == user.UserID)
                select user.UserName).ToList()
```

can be written as the following lambda expression as well:

```
    var list = db.Users.Where(user => !db.Fi.Any(f => f.UserID == user.UserID))
               .Select(user => user.UserName).ToList()
```

which from the looks of it is slightly different from Kirill Bestemyanov's answer (which I slightly modified, just to make it look more similar):

```
    var list = db.Users.Where(user => !db.Fi.Select(f => f.UserID)
                                            .Contains(user.UserID))
                              .Select(user => user.UserName).ToList();
```

But, they will in fact produce the same SQL Statement, thus the same list.

Answer (score 9):

I will rewrite it to linq extension methods:

```
List<string> listString = db.Users.Where(e=>!db.Fi.Select(m=>m.UserID)
                                                  .Contains(e.UserID))
                                  .Select(e=>e.UserName).ToList();
```

try it, it should work.

Comment: I was worried this would generate a bunch of SQL calls, but it converted it into the proper SQL thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Try this it is very simple.

```
var result=(from e in db.Users
            select e.UserID).Except(from m in db.Fi
                                    select m.UserID).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var res = db.tbl_Ware.Where(
    a => a.tbl_Buy.Where(
        c =>c.tbl_Ware.Title.Contains(
            mtrTxtWareTitle.Text)).Select(b => b.Ware_ID).Contains(a.ID));
```

this mean in T-SQL is :

```
select * 
from tbl_Ware 
where id in (
    select ware_ID tbl_Buy where tbl_Ware.title like '% mtrTxtwareTitle.Text %')
```